# Take input from IP_webcam, manipulate & pump it out

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, video-capture

I want to take the input from a standard, off the shelf, IP based webcam - which, has yet to be decided, so the API is not yet clear - manipulate it a little and then pump it back out so that others can view my manipulated image.

Given that this is a little vague, which technologies can you recommend?

I am thinking to use an Adroid slate, to save costs, so it's probably Java coding. So, how best to get an image stream (plus void, modify the stream and send the modified video plus unmodified audio?

I might also add file transfer & IM chat into the mix ...

FOSS solutions highly welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most IP cameras produce RTP/RTSP with jmpeg, mpeg4 or h.264 encoded stream.

You would need to write a RTP/RTSP client and then a decoder for the particular stream, then manipulate images, reencode stream and serve it over some standard protocol (again probably RTP/RTSP).

Not something Android devices are powerful enough to do. Also there are no pure Java libs that can do this.

What you should use is [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/). If you need to serve streams to Flash and/or iPhone you should add [Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) or [Red5](http://www.red5.org/).

Comment: +1 Thanks, that looks like some good info. It is not yet final, but we will probably go with H.264.   The reason that I wanted to interrupt the data stream is that it is going over satellite link, which can be expensive, so I thought to not repeat identical frames. Any ideas?  As to writing a decoder, I think I'll be looking on sourceforge. As to Android, I guess it's the same with Linux slate PCs - puny processor. It might have to be a ruggedized laptop, which increases cost there & reduce it on satellite time - always trade-offs.

Comment: p.s XUgger looks good. I'll just have to run some trials on Adnroid slates. Otoh, since I want to avoid repeating identical frames, I don't need to decompress them, just compare. On the other, other hand, I guess that even a small change makes a big difference to the frame. Maybe I'll reserve this for v2.0